# How to use LEFT() function on range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to return the reference for the cell that starts with "Total".

Example rows (A1:A4):

```
Students
Lecturers
Tutors
Total
```

Using `=MATCH("Total",A$1:A$10,0)` returns 4, however in the real data, the value in A4 will be "Total XZY" depending on the contents, so I need to compare only on the first 5 characters of the cell.

Using `=MATCH("Total",LEFT(A$1:A$10,5),0)` returns `#VALUE!` error.  When I go into the function editor window I can see that the formula is correctly being evaluated and resulting in 4, but it is not returning this.  Image attached below.

Why is this happening and how can I achieve the desired result please?

[image: From within the formula window]

Comment: Confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: But you can use wildcards with match. `=MATCH("Total*",A1:A10,0)`

Comment: Thanks, both options work.

Comment: @ScottCraner  It works, but is there any way to activate it using vba ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, the only thing you missed is that as this is an array and it will not work with a regular function. Try pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you have created your MATCH function. It will look like this in the formula bar:{=MATCH("Total",LEFT($A$2:$A$6,5),0)} (Substitute your range with whatever range desired)